# Allowing individual users to hide entries

Tags: channel-entries, entry, list

I've got an Intranet with a list of job postings (each of which are channel entries), and I need to give each logged-in user the ability to click a button to hide an individual entry from their listings.

Each user has their own user profile channel entry (I'm using Profile:Edit for this), so I imagine that adding a custom field to their profile named 'My Hidden Entries' is the way to go. I'm thinking that a field which saves entry ID's in a pipe-separated list would be good, as it'd mean I can use them in a channel entries tag to hide their hidden entries (entry_id="not {cf_user_hidden_entries}"), as well as being able to use the opposite method to generate a list of entries a user has hidden (entry_id="{cf_user_hidden_entries}").

My question is, does this approach sound good? And if so, what fieldtype would you recommend to use that would save entry ID's in a custom field in this format, and allow me to easily add/remove entries from their list? It's the adding and removing of entries that I'm particularly concerned about, as this will be done outside the CP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be honest, I would suggest using an addon like '[LikEE](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/likee)' which allows you to toggle an entry in some way. Obviously the natural suggestion is for 'liking' entries - however, you could use it whereby, you list the jobs and when a user 'likes' it - it's the indication to remove it.

Then inside your exp channel loop - simply do something like the following:

```
{exp:channel:entries .... }
    {exp:likee entry_id="{entry_id}"}
      {if "{like}"}
       // They've liked it, so don't do anything
      {if:else}
      // Put your job logic here
      {/if}
    {/exp:likee}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

You might need to fiddle with the syntax - however, this would potentially be an easy way of doing it without messing with posting entries and channel updates etc.

Comment: This add-on allows you to "Like" or "Dislike" something. So you could use the "Like" for its actual purpose and then use "Dislike" as a basis to hide entries. http://booyant.com/likee/getting-started

Comment: Thanks for this. I like the idea and think this is a much nicer way to go. :)